# correct intermediate values to ensure order in table where is needed a date and number correlative order (number is unique)

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have a table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items
(
    item_number integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('items_nro_seq'::regclass),
    item_date date,
    CONSTRAINT items_pk PRIMARY KEY (item_number)
);
```

Logic constraints:

- item_number is unique and correlative.
- in a certain item_date can be a lot of values for item_number
- for an item_number X higher than an item_number Y, is an error (but can exist) when X.item_date < Y.item_date.

Sample data:

| item_number | item_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1856 | 2023-10-21 |
| 1855 | 2023-10-21 |
| 1854 | 2023-10-22 |
| 1853 | 2023-10-22 |
| 1852 | 2023-10-21 |
| 1851 | 2023-10-21 |
| 1850 | 2023-10-21 |

I need a solution that identifies and changes item_date for item_number, 1853 and 1854 in sample data, to '2023-10-21'.

| item_number | item_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1856 | 2023-10-21 |
| 1855 | 2023-10-21 |
| **1854** | **2023-10-21** |
| **1853** | **2023-10-21** |
| 1852 | 2023-10-21 |
| 1851 | 2023-10-21 |
| 1850 | 2023-10-21 |

I have tried with row_number and lag functions. I tried with a query with a subquery. I tried defining functions and iterate.
The best result I get is to change values for item_number 1855 and 1856 to '2023-10-22'. That's not a solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION correct_dates() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    item record;
    actual_date date;
BEGIN
    FOR item IN
        SELECT item_number, item_date
        FROM items
        ORDER BY nro, fecha
    LOOP
        IF item.item_date < actual_date THEN
            UPDATE items
            SET item_date = actual_date
            WHERE item_number = item.item_number AND item_date = item.item_date;
        ELSE
            actual_date := item.item_date;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Comment: 1) This `item_number integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('items_nro_seq'::regclass)` is not guaranteed to provide a gapless or strictly ordered set of `item_number`s relative to other values in the row. 2) This is a fragile system that depends on something that is not guaranteed in SQL, which is ordering. You really rethink what you are trying to achieve. 3) Bottom line a process that depends on you going back to periodically correct it is mostly likely wrong.

Comment: Sequence values, identity values, etc, should only ever be relied on for uniqueness. Relying on ordering, and especially consecutiveness, is a code-smell (misuse of behaviours not guaranteed in all circumstances).

Comment: Both are rigth, nothing to said. Item_number is unique and is ordered. Take that as a guarantee. Is there a way to achieve what i need? Perhaps i forget about some function like lag?